# Why are writes to python serial port output buffer captured by reads from input buffer

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port

I trying to write commands to a python serial port, and
capture response from the connected device on the input
channel of the port buffer.

I need to capture the reads, as and when they occur, so I create a 
thread which reads if the input buffer is none empty.

When I run the program I see the data I output to the output
buffer on the input buffer of the serial port.

The code I created is shown below:

```
import threading
import serial
import json
import time


def handle_data(data):
    print(data)


def read_from_port(serPort):
        while True:
            if serPort.in_waiting > 0:
                # print("in:", serPort.in_waiting)
                reading = serPort.read(serPort.in_waiting).decode('ascii')
                handle_data(reading)
            time.sleep(0.1)


ser = serial.Serial(
  port='COM15',
  baudrate=115200,
  timeout=0
)

thread = threading.Thread(target=read_from_port, args=(ser,))
thread.start()

print(ser.name)

jsonDict = {
    'c': 120,
    'i': 0,
    'p': '',
}

i = 1
while i < 1000:
    jsonDict["i"] = i
    if i%2 == 0:
        cmd = (2 << 8) | 0
        payload = "local"
    else:
        cmd = (1 << 8) | 100
        payload = "remote"

    jsonDict["c"] = cmd
    jsonDict["p"] = payload
    output = json.dumps(jsonDict) + '\r'
    ser.write(output)
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(1)

ser.close()
```

To test the python functionality, I'm currently routing 
data sent to the connected device with payload "local", back to the pc.

However the read thread is capturing both the the data that is sent and the data which is returned, see below:

```
COM15


{"i": 1, "p": "remote", "c": 356}

{"i": 2, "p": "local", "c": 512}

{"i": 2, "p": "local", "c": 512}
{"i": 3, "p": "remote", "c": 356}

{"i": 4, "p": "local", "c": 512}

{"i": 4, "p": "local", "c": 512}
{"i": 5, "p": "remote", "c": 356}

{"i": 6, "p": "local", "c": 512}

{"i": 6, "p": "local", "c": 512}
{"i": 7, "p": "remote", "c": 356}

{"i": 8, "p": "local", "c": 512}

{"i": 8, "p": "local", "c": 512}
{"i": 9, "p": "remote", "c": 356}
```

Any thoughts!

Comment: Does the device do echo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code. You probably can open a [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) or [Tera-Term](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en) terminal and see the exact same behavior - some devices have the option to echo back the sent commands (this is helpful when working from terminal).
You didn't said what device you are using but this is probably can be configured - search for 'echo' configuration on your device.
More exotic problem might be Tx line shorted to the Rx line somewhere along the connection wire but I'll check this only after eliminating the echo configuration.

If the echo can't be configured you'll just have to deal with it in code.

Comment: Ok I'll try it out